# multiple items in paypal

Tags: paypal

Trying to send multiple items to a paypal cart and having problems:

This (single item) works fine:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="1st Item" /> 

<input type="image" src="addcart.gif" name="submit" alt="cart add" />
</form>
```

This (multiple items, seems to be suggested solution) fires an error on the cart page that reads "PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem.":
<

```
form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />

<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="20.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="1st Item" /> 

<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="20.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="2nd Item" /> 

<input type="image" src="addcart.gif" name="submit" alt="cart add" />
</form>
```

Two forms (below) work fine, but I am trying to get the submission done with one form and one click.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="1st Item" /> 

<input type="image" src="addcart.gif" name="submit" alt="cart add" />
</form>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="2nd Item" /> 

<input type="image" src="addcart.gif" name="submit" alt="cart add" />
</form>
```

If I use the following, it works fine, but it doesn't go to the cart page, rather a "Choose your way to pay" page

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />

<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="20.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="1st Item" /> 

<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="20.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="2nd Item" /> 

<input type="image" src="addcart.gif" name="submit" alt="cart add" />
</form>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `<input type="hidden" name="display" value="1" />` in your most recent/last example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not be able to add multiple items to the cart at once, when using the add to cart button which is indicated by the following two lines of code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
```

You have to use the cart upload command, to be able to upload mutlipe items as once.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
```

The reason that it does not take you to cart page, is this method is what you would be using if you were using a 3rd party cart, or a customized cart.  If you are wanting to show the buyers what is in their cart, you would need to do this on your webiste prior to passing the data over to PayPal.  On your website, they would add, remove or adjust the quantity and then when they are ready to checkout is when you would redirect the buyer over to PayPal to pay.