# Submit only one form from foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, submit, social-networking

I'm having a problem submitting only one of the forms at my site.
 
The forms are being created dynamic through a foreach loop.

Every time i'm submitting one form, it submits all of them, so if there is 10 posts then they have a reply form each, and all it inserted to the database.

```
<div id="newsFeed">

<div class='newsBox'>
    <div class="newsProfileInfo">
        <div class="newsProfileImg">
            <img src="<?php echo $path, $res->profileImage;?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>">
        </div><!--newsProfileInfo ends here-->


        <div class="newsName">
            <p>
                <?php echo $res->name." ".$res->surname;?>
            </p>
        </div><!--newsName-->

    </div><!--newsProfileInfo ends here-->


    <div class="newPost">
        <form action='' method='post'>

            <textarea name="newPost" placeholder="Opret nyt indlæg"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" name="postSubmit" value="Opret">
        </form>
    </div>
```

```
<?php 
    $data = newsFeed($db);

    foreach($data as $news){

        $newsId     = $news['newsId'];
        $headline   = $news['headline'];
        $post       = $news['post'];
        $date       = $news['postDate'];
        $dates      = date_create($date);

        $name       = $news['name'];
        $surname    = $news['surname'];
        $profileImg = $news['profileImage'];

        $path = "images/profileImages/";
```

?>

```
<div class="newsProfileInfo">
    <div class="newsProfileImg">
        <img src="<?php echo $path, $profileImg;?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>">
    </div><!--newsProfileInfo ends here-->

    <div class="newsName">
        <p><a href=""><?php echo substr($name ." ". $surname, 0,11);?></a></p>
    </div><!--newsName-->

    <p class="postDate">
        <?php echo date_format($dates, 'd/m/Y') ." - ".date_format($dates,'H:i');?>
    </p>

</div><!--newsProfileInfo ends here-->


<div class="newsPost">
    <p>
        <?php echo $post;?>
    </p>
</div>



<?php
    $reply = replyToPost($db,$newsId);

    foreach($reply as $msg){


        $replyId    = $msg['replyId'];
        $message    = $msg['message'];
        $news_fk    = $msg['newsId_fk'];
        $userId_fk  = $msg['userId_fk'];
        $date       = $msg['date'];
        $name       = $msg['name'];
        $surname    = $msg['surname'];
        $profileImg = $msg['profileImage'];

        $path = "images/profileImages/";
?>

<div class="replysLoop">
    <div class="replyImg">
        <img src="<?php echo $path, $profileImg;?>" alt="<?php echo $name;?>">
    </div>

    <div class="replysBoxes">
        <p><?php echo $message;?></p>
    </div><!--replysBoxes ends here-->


</div><!--replysLoop ends here-->

<?php
    }
?>

<div class="replyToMsg">

    <div class="replyImg">
        <img src="<?php echo $path, $res->profileImage;?>" alt="<?php echo $res->name; ?>">
    </div>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['replySubmit'])){
        insertReply($db,$newsId);
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    ?>

    <div class="inputHolder">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="replys" placeholder="Besvar indlæg">
            <input type="submit" name="replySubmit" value="Besvar">
        </form>
    </div>

</div>

</div><!--newsbox ends here-->
```

```
    <?php                  
        }//foreach loop newsfeed ends here
    ?>
```

Comment: this is not te full code? show some screenshot of your all forms and also try to put your code and wheres the problem occur?

Comment: your question is not clear. please describe it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware the submit button will only submit the form that it is in. In fact it is very hard to submit more than one form at a time.

I suspect the problem is that the form submits the reply and that it is not bound to a current comment and ends up getting added to all of them.

I suggest that you start with something like this:

```
<?php
//... something that results in this post setting `$postid`
?>
<div class="reply">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="replyToPostID" value="<?php echo $postid; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="replyToPost" placeholder="Besvar indlæg">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Then your `PHP` can make `SQL` that pins the comment down to one parent comment. Of course you are forcing me to guess because there is no way what you have posted is the entire code.

- See also: [Submit Multiple Forms With One Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667765/submit-multiple-forms-with-one-button)

Comment: Hi that worked thanks. No the full code i really long so thought i'd spare you all for the full one. + it has lots of functions that was not important for the problem.. But Thanks

Comment: No probs. You gave me enough information to get a good estimate of what was going on.

Comment: Perfect. but it still inserts the comment as many times as there is forms displayed

Comment: It sounds like you need to post a new question with your code for processing forms as there might be further issues there.