# how to multiple post form with single button and open all in new tab

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 3 postform with same func, but i do different message,

how to create a single button to execute all button(1,2,3)? and with single button than open new tab of each button(1,2,3).

```
<?php $url = "http://example.com"; ?>

<form id="postform" action="<?php echo "$url" ?>/action.php" method="post" name="postform" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="message">
        <tbody id="post-message">
            <div id="post-subject">
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="subject 1"></input>
            </div>
            <div id="post-message">
                <textarea name="message" id="code-message">message 1 here</textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="post-buttons">
                <td id="post-buttons"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="button 1"></td>
            </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<form id="postform" action="<?php echo "$url" ?>/action.php" method="post" name="postform" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="message">
        <tbody id="post-message">
            <div id="post-subject">
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="subject 2"></input>
            </div>
            <div id="post-message">
                <textarea name="message" id="code-message">message 2 here</textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="post-buttons">
                <td id="post-buttons"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="button 2"></td>
            </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<form id="postform" action="<?php echo "$url" ?>/action.php" method="post" name="postform" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="message">
        <tbody id="post-message">
            <div id="post-subject">
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="subject 3"></input>
            </div>
            <div id="post-message">
                <textarea name="message" id="code-message">message 3 here</textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="post-buttons">
                <td id="post-buttons"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="button 3"></td>
            </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean "execute all button"?   This question is very unclear.  What do you want it to "execute"?  If you want all three "forms" submitted, just combine them into a single form...?  Unless you combine them into a single form, there's no practical way to do this without using javascript, but even that seems off / incorrect.

Comment: i just want to submit my 3 different messages with 1 click button, 
in my form, i have 3 button, so i must click one by one.
can u give me a solutions sir? thanks for reply

Comment: Sure.  Make it all a single form instead of 3 separate forms, and change the names of the three textarea to be different.

Comment: so i can't to open 3 new tab with different showing my message with one click? if i make all it to a single form, is't that just 1 tab? can u help give me a sample sir?

Comment: As I said before, this is not possible **without javascript**.

Comment: can u get me a reference with js? thanks for this discus sir

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667765/submit-multiple-forms-with-one-button

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `if(isset()) {...}` statement.
For example:

Form 1

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
    ...
}
```

Form 2

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
    ...
}
```

Form 3
    ...

Form 4........

Comment: How does this solve the problem of submitting three separate forms with a single button?

Comment: Oh, im sorry, i didnt get the question speseficly! I will do an edit

Comment: thanks sir,
can u give me a sample including with my form?

Comment: I just have to be sure, you want to open 3 subject pages with the spesefic subject and you want 1 button to do it??

Comment: yes sir, and this result will show my different message from respond action page,

Comment: If you installed my file you will see i entered `<textfield></textfield>`, and thats wrong, you will have to change it to `<textarea></textarea>`