# PHP unable to grab name of dynamically generated forms

Tags: php, forms, post, dynamic, undefined

I'm trying to update my database, based on a value in a textbox. The first foreach loop is working fine ($emails is grabbed from another class), but in the second loop I am unable to grab the name of each form ("form_UD") without getting an undefined index error. I'm also pretty sure that my syntax in the second foreach loop is wrong. What I'm trying to do is check that for each of these forms, if the user clicks its corresponding "btn_update" button, then call the $RUD class' updateEmail method and insert the value from this button, as well as the value from the form's corresponding "input_email" value.

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
            echo "<li>
                    <form action='' method='POST' id='form_email' name='form_UD'>
                        <input type='text' value='" . $email['news_email'] . "' name='input_email'/>
                        <button type='submit' class='btn_update' name='btn_update' value='" . $email['news_id'] . "'>Update</button>
                    </form>
                </li>";
        }
        foreach (($_POST['form_UD']) as $form) {
            if ((isset($form->$_POST['btn_update']))) {
            $RUD->updateEmail($form->$_POST['btn_update'], $form->$_POST['input_email']);
        }
```

***EDIT:*** New idea:

```
        <form action='' method='POST' id='form_email'>
        <ul>
        <?php
            foreach ($emails as $email) {
                echo "<li>
                        <input type='text' value='" . $email['news_email'] . "' name='input_email" . $email['news_id'] . "'/>
                        <button type='submit' class='btn_update' name='btn_update" . $email['news_id'] . "' value='" . $email['news_id'] . "'>Update</button>
                    </li>";
            }

            foreach ($emails as $email) {
                if (isset($_POST['btn_update' . $email['news_id']])) {
                    echo $_POST['btn_update' . $email['news_id']];
                    echo $_POST['input_email' . $email['news_id']];
                    $RUD->updateEmail(($_POST['btn_update' . $email['news_id']]), ($_POST['input_email' . $email['news_id']]));
                }
            }
        ?>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

The echo statements are getting the correct values on click. By the way, $RUD was instantiated elsewhere in the same file. This leads me to believe there may be an issue in my method that's handling the update? Here it is:

```
public function updateEmail($id, $email){

    $db = Dbclass::getDB();
    $query = "UPDATE newsletter
            SET news_email = :email,
            WHERE id = :id ";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $statement->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

Dbclass:getDB() does work. I confirmed it with other methods.

Comment: where is the foreach $key and $value?

Comment: @unixmiah Foreach doesn't require output to key value.  When only a single var is supplied it will be the value.  foreach($var as $key => $val) or foreach($var as $val) are both valid syntax for foreach in PHP.

Comment: your form_UD part in the form needs to be read like $array['form_UD'] --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working code:

Main PHP file:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="form_email">
        <ul>
        <?php
            foreach ($emails as $email) {
                echo "<li>
                        <input type='text' value='" . $email['news_email'] . "' name='input_email" . $email['news_id'] . "'/>
                        <button type='submit' class='btn_update' name='btn_update" . $email['news_id'] . "' value='" . $email['news_id'] . "'>Update</button>
                    </li>";
            }

            foreach ($emails as $email) {
                if (isset($_POST['btn_update' . $email['news_id']])) {
                    $RUD->updateEmail(($_POST['btn_update' . $email['news_id']]), ($_POST['input_email' . $email['news_id']]));
                }
            }
        ?>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Method in class RUD:

```
  public function updateEmail($id, $email){

    $db = Dbclass::getDB();
    $query = "UPDATE newsletter
            SET news_email = :email
            WHERE news_id = :id ";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $statement->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

I had some silly typos/errors in my SQL statement...removed a comma after ":email" in WHERE clause, and updated "id" to be the proper "news_id" from the table. Ha!

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong - but I don't believe this is possible unless you submit via XHR.  The reason is that you have 1 submit button to 1 form to submit that form - you can not submit many forms from within a form with a submit, it will only submit that form the submit button exists as child element of and it will arrive in your $_POST.

There is no ability to submit ALL forms via 1 button without client side scripting and preparing the statement as $_GET request or XHR post (get could be used as well via XHR).  Generally you would name inputs with [] in the name to signify it as an array on a form when you want the inputs to arrive as an array value.

You seem to be trying to use form as an array and assuming it arrives as an array of objects with all of the input elements as array elements of a property named after the form - which is not how this works.  Maybe there is some darker art now available for PHP that I haven't seen or been exposed to but I doubt it, it has been a while since I handled a form in this method.

Check out: [Submit Multiple Forms With One Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667765/submit-multiple-forms-with-one-button) for how to do this via XHR.

Further details on XHR: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

Check out this link for the HTML5 form standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html

A simpler write up can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Further read this on how this works with PHP:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Finally read this for how $_POST works:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Again, I could be wrong but it's doubtful.

Added example of debugging code from comment below:

```
if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) {
    print_r($_POST);
    die();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to submit all forms at once. The only reason why I created multiple forms was in an attempt to group the input buttons with their respective input text fields. I'm open to other options. I need a way to say "when a button is clicked, send its value, as well as the value of the text input field right beside it, as parameters in my method".

Comment: Ok then you are fine - you are just handling the $_POST incorrectly.  Do this to see what you are getting: 
print_r($_POST); 
die();

View the input you received - you should receive only the form and the field(s) that you have submitted via your submit button of that collection of input elements within the parent form.  print_r and var_dump will give you insight into what you are working with in your PHP script so you know what you are getting and in what format.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Where should I put this code? I can't put it inside the if block because it can't even read the 'form_UD's that have been dynamically generated.

Comment: Where you are handling your form - you could even do this:

if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) {
print_r($_POST);
die();
}

That way it only runs if $_POST is set.  This is for debugging only so you have insight into the data arriving or being used in your code.  When you don't need to debug - comment it out or remove it.  Learn to use print_r and var_dump for debugging and your life will be easier.  (This is debugging and the particular style is 'caveman' debugging). Check my edit to the comment for a clearer example of the debug code.

Comment: Thanks. I actually came up with a new idea. I think it's close to working. Can you please check out my original question for the new edited part?

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out. I had some typos in my SQL statement...got rid of the comma in ":email," and replaced "id" with the proper one from the table "news_id". I submitted an answer to the question. Thank you for all your help!