# Multiple input forms for the same mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

After creating a form which inserts the values into my mysql table I was wondering which would be the appropriate way to add more then one form on the same page to be able to insert more lines of data into the given table?

Thanks to everyone in advance for every suggestion :)

Btw I found this : `http://jsfiddle.net/kXmpY/1/` `onclick` duplicating the whole form would be perfect but it wont duplicate it :(

Here is the input form :

```
<form action="" method="post">
<p>Title:<br /> <input name="pageTitle" type="text" value="" size="103" /></p>
<p>content<br /><textarea name="pageCont" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button" /></p>
</form>


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){$title = $_POST['pageTitle'];
$content = $_POST['pageCont'];

$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($content);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO pages (pageTitle,pageCont) VALUES ('$title','$content')")or die(mysql_error());
$_SESSION['success'] = 'Page Added';
header('Location: '.DIRADMIN);
exit();
}
```

Comment: Please add more information. Maybe add code snippets too. This is way too broad and probably going to lead to opinionated answers

Comment: edited, thank  you for the suggestion :)

Comment: If you add more forms, then each form will have it's own submit and each form will be posted separately. What you have to do is to clone elements inside your form you need to be duplicated and then capture them in your `php` after the post and insert them one by one in the db

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, i got this working so far http://jsfiddle.net/kXmpY/2084/ , now i am looking for some way to submit all with one submit button, should be doable ? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667765/submit-multiple-forms-with-one-button)